# What context free grammar generates the language $L(G) = \{a^ib^jc^{2i}d^m\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I am struggling to think of the context-free grammar that generates the language $L(G) = \{a^ib^jc^{2i}d^m\}$, where $i$, $j$ and $m$ are natural numbers.

Also, in general, are there any good methods or ways of thinking that help one to think of context free grammars that generate a given language. Any tips are much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
 I've tried S →ABCD, A →aA | λ, B →bB | λ, 
C →ccC | λ, D →dD | λ

However, this doesn't allow for always generating twice the amount of c's as there are a's.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For me, it always helps how to imagine how a corresponding derivation tree looks like. Also, it is useful to identify what "parts" of a word depend on each other and, hence, might need to be generated with the same rule.

Comment: I'm stuck on matching the a's and c's and I've added on what I tried to the original post. And thank you Dan, I'll try and use those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching number of a and c you need to do something like this:

$$
S \rightarrow AB \\
A \rightarrow aAcc \\
A \rightarrow C \\
C \rightarrow bC | λ \\
B \rightarrow dB | λ 
$$

You need to produce them in one rule to be sure the ratio is kept.